# Populate menu list with multiple text files using php

Tags: php, jquery, content-management-system, navigation

I'm trying to build a kiosk on a local machine, so no online requirement. I am going to build a big menu which will show exhibition stores and products. Due to the stores and products will always change, the client has requested to use a simple text file - .txt to populate the menu.

I used jQuery last week but unfortunately it didn't work. So after searching I've decided to use php instead. I'm new to php, but I have given it a try today, I have only managed to populate one list with the external file kate.txt

Here is my code for the page

```
<body>
    <ul class="sf-menu">
        <li class="current">
            <a href="#a">Area1</a>
            <ul>
                <li class="current">
                    <a href="#ab">Kate</a>
                    <ul>
                        <?php
                            //variables
                            $dir = "C:\wamp\www\Menu";
                            $txtfile="Textfiles\kate.txt";
                            foreach (glob("$txtfile") as $filename) {   
                                $file = $filename;
                                $contents = file($file); 
                                $string = implode("<li>", $contents);
                            }
                        ?>                      
                        <li><a href="#"><?php echo $string ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>    
                    <a href="#">Cathy</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Banana</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Apple</a></li>      
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Area2</a>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">lily</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Watermelon</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Grapefruit</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">John</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Orange</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Pineapple</a></li>          
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li> <!--current-->
    </ul> <!--sf-menu-->
</body>
```

Can someone please give me some direction on the php code? I don't mind how the text files are structured in a folder, as long as I can populate all the menu list items and links with a text file or multiple text files not in the html code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your text file holds all your list items

kate.txt:

```
<li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
<li><a href="#">stuff</a></li>
...
```

the php file

```
<?php
  $txtfile="Textfiles\kate.txt";
  $content = file_get_contents($txtfile);

<li class="current">
   <a href="#ab">Kate</a>
   <ul>
   <?php echo $content ?>
   </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: Hi Ibu and Elad,Ibu thanks for the suggestion unfortunately it didn't work. When I put the code in, all the content shows in one list only. I'm trying to populate all the lists in the menu, please see the code. Any other suggestions? Thank you for your time. S

Comment: i suggest using a database, it is way more effective than a text file, and very easy to use. go MySQL